# How to check daylight saving enable for timezone using offset value

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I want to convert local date&time to various timezone by using offset value. I am taking reference from https://www.techrepublic.com/article/convert-the-local-time-to-another-time-zone-with-this-javascript/ link to convert date&time conversion based on the offset value.

I want to check whether Daylight Saving is currently enabled or not for a particular timezone using offset value. I have tried with below moment js.

```
 var time = moment(time).isDST();
```

It checks my local timezone

```
 var isdst = moment(time).zone(offset);
```

Both the above code is providing the wrong value.

I am getting only offset value from the back end. So I am not able to use

```
moment().tz("America/New_York").isDST();
```

How can I find whether daylight saving is currently enabled or not using offset value?